# Why PropertyChanged is always null?

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

PropertyChanged is always null and name is not displayed on the window. It supposed to be Roman. Do you know why its always null and not diplaying the name?

My windows class

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string _name;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string PersonName
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        _name = "Adam";
        PersonName = "Roman";
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Label x:Name="Test" Width="100" Height="50" Foreground="Black" Content="{Binding PersonName, Mode=TwoWay}"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where do you set the DataContext in your XAML? Without setting the DataContext somewhere your bindings won't work.

Comment: I didnt know I have to set DataContext, Now its working , thanks

Comment: If you're in the code behind anyway, what's the point in this?

Comment: Put the INPC properties in a viewmodel class. Assign an instance of the viewmodel class to the DataContext property of your MainWindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In public `public MainWindow()` added `this.DataContext = this` and its working

Looks like

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _name = "Adam";
        PersonName = "Roman";
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
```